# R package installation fails on Mac M1 (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')

Tags: r

A colleague provided an home-made R package which installs without any problem on my older Mac at home but does not on an M1 MacBook Pro. I do not know how I can provide a reproducible example; hence I copy the error below.

I found instances of errors with "have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'" on Stackoverflow but reading the replies did not help resolve the issue. Some of these replies exceed my technical abilities. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I used the install.packages function as below:

```
install.packages("~/kDrive/Documents/experiments/exp177_arctic_light/R/SolarSpectrum/SolarSpectrum_1.2.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
Installing package into ‘/Users/gattuso/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘SolarSpectrum’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
using C compiler: ‘Homebrew clang version 12.0.1’
using SDK: ‘’
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include    -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c solarspectrum3.c -o solarspectrum3.o

.....


Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘SolarSpectrum’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Users/gattuso/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/00LOCK-SolarSpectrum/00new/SolarSpectrum/libs/SolarSpectrum.so':
  dlopen(/Users/gattuso/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/00LOCK-SolarSpectrum/00new/SolarSpectrum/libs/SolarSpectrum.so, 0x0006): tried: '/Users/gattuso/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/00LOCK-SolarSpectrum/00new/SolarSpectrum/libs/SolarSpectrum.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/gattuso/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/00LOCK-SolarSpectrum/00new/SolarSpectrum/libs/SolarSpectrum.so' (no such file), '/Users/gattuso/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/00LOCK-SolarSpectrum/00new/SolarSpectrum/libs/SolarSpectrum.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64'))
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
```

Comment: Does the home-made package have pre-compiled libraries written in C/C++/etc.? From the error, it seems that may be the case.

Comment: Think of `arm64` and `x64_64` as "diesel" and "petrol".  While they both power cars, they are not interchangeable in a mix and match sense: no diesel can fuel a petrol engine.  Get the _source code_ from your colleague and install the package from source.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, that is a _splendid_ analogy, unless of course the reader does not (yet) know the cost of putting gas in a diesel engine (or reverse). Having experienced that (the gas station was contaminated), it is bad.

Comment: However, it does look like this is a source installation (the `.tar.gz` hints at this). I wonder if the tarball you got has a stale `.so` (or `.library` or whatever) file within it that will cause the `make` process to not recompile specific components. Remove such compiled object/library files before attempting to install/compile it; likely this means untarring it and navigating to the `./src/` directory (and any subdirs) manually.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel  I agree, and might even suggest the OP **build** a package from source (which is probably what you implied but didn't specify)

Comment: Many thanks for the comments and suggestions. I will meet today with a colleague much more knowledgeable that I am. Hopefully this will make sense to him. I will report back on this thread.

Comment: I found the solution [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/issues-installing-stanheaders-rstan-on-a-macbook-m1/169902/18)

cat ~/.R/Makevars
…
That seems like a compiler setup for an older version of R.
You can set it aside with
mv ~/.R/Makevars ~/.R/Makevars.bak
and then chances are that rstan will be working. Or you'll at least get a different error.
You installed a custom compiler at some point, but its setup (in ~/.R/Makevars) was broken for some reason that is impossible to tell now.
By removing that file now you are back to the default compilers in Xcode.